# Group by and join unique values in other columns by delimiter in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have some columns in dataframe and I would like to group by them be some columns and join other unique column values by '|'. The example dataframe is:

```
col1 col2                           col3        col4    col5       col6                                             
0    Paralysis|Postictal paralysis  1234|4567   1234    5647474    meddra
0    Paralysis|Postictal paralysis  1234|4567   4567    5363737    meddra
```

I would like to group by this dataframe by col1, col2, and col3 and join unique values in other columns by '|'.

The expected output is:

```
col1 col2                           col3        col4         col5              col6                                             
0    Paralysis|Postictal paralysis  1234|4567   1234|4567    5647474|5363737   meddra
```

I am running below lines to get the desired out but I am not getting it.

```
df.groupby(['col1', 'col2', 'col3']).agg(lambda col: '|'.join(col))
```

Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: `.agg(lambda col: '|'.join(col.unique().astype(str)))`